# How fix empty border line after spanning cells in table?

Tags: python, html, pyqt, border

I am working about python script and I use PyQt4. When I try spanning with function `setSpan(row, col, rowSpanWidth, colSpanWidth)` and apply on cell with "author". I am getting this result, borderline cleared and I do not know why. Spanning works fine on cells inside table or another (right) side/edge. Left side is not right.

final table

[image]

Could anyone give me please a tip what I should do to span good or advice for that?

Code:

```
self.table = QTableWidget()
self.table.setRowCount(7)
self.table.setColumnCount(2)
self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

# add data into table
for indexRow, row in enumerate(tableDict):
    for indexCol, col in enumerate(tableDict[indexRow]):
        self.table.setItem(indexRow, indexCol, QTableWidgetItem(tableDict[indexRow][indexCol]))

self.table.setSpan(3, 0, 2, 1)

# table is readable only
self.table.setStyleSheet("border:0px;")
self.table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
self.table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.table.setShowGrid(True)

self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()`
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I added my part of code when I work with table

Comment: I can reproduce it in both qt-4.8.7 and qt-5.10.1. It seems to be a bug, but I couldn't find anything related to it on the [tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: I was thinking if it is not bug... Thanks for help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying fix the bug, I found unclear solution, but mainly it works :-)

1) Add extra empty column on side when border is not show correct.
2) Span column with data inside table.
3) Set extra column width as 1px (it makes line only).

Code:

```
self.table = QTableWidget()
self.table.setRowCount(7)
self.table.setColumnCount(2 + 1)    # added 1 extra column
self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

# add data into table
for indexRow, row in enumerate(tableDict):
    for indexCol, col in enumerate(tableDict[indexRow]):
        self.table.setItem(indexRow, indexCol + 1, QTableWidgetItem(tableDict[indexRow][indexCol]))

self.table.setSpan(3, 0 + 1, 2, 1)

# table is readable only
self.table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
self.table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.table.setShowGrid(True)

self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
self.table.setColumnWidth(0, 1)    # need to be after resizeColumnsToContents(), or it will not works
```

[Right result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4szo.png)